# Is there a sudent solution manual for applied analysis by john K. Hunter and Bruno Nachtergaele?

Tags: reference-request

Is there a sudent solution manual for applied analysis by john K. Hunter and Bruno Nachtergaele?
especially for chapter 11 Distributions and the Fourier Transform?
if not is there another book about the same chapter with solution manual?